# imagefield never upload in my template

Tags: python, django

i am user django, i create my dynamic blog site with dadabase and templates htmal/css to upload my new post fine.

now i want to upload on my post some images for that i create new field in my database

```
image1 = model.imagefield(upload_to="/images/imagethumb/")
```

i  can login with admin and create new post with the photo but the photo never to see my template.

From my research in the internet, i think the my problem in my `settings.py` or `upload_to` for `media_root` and `media_url` and apache folder.my `/images/imagethumb/` must in the media folder?

Comment: Pycharm is an IDE and has nothing to do with your website issues. You should include all code relevant to your issue to help diagnose the issue

Answer (score 2):

Add following in your settings.py file

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Create 'media' in your project at same level as your 'manage.py'.
Now add following line at end of your project urls.py file.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Now your image will be stored in /media directory.
You can access it by following path

> /media/image.png

It will be good if you share directory structure as well.

```
mysite
      your_app
      mysite
            urls.py
      media
      manage.py
```

You will have to add above mentioned line in urls.py shown in above directory structure.

Comment: how to create 'media' at same level as 'manage.py' ? my folder is mysite and in that folder i have .idea,blog(my app),mysite,templates,db sqlite and manage.py.....and in the folder blog i have __pycache__,migrations,templates,init,admin,models,test,urls and views...and i have in my project two urls.py one mysite/urls.py and two blog/urls which of the two urls add the last line urlpatterns

Comment: create media folder under mysite (main one not under mysite/mysite/).

Comment: I have updated answer with directory structure.

Comment: ok i test now and i share you thnx

Comment: and the 'image1 = model.imagefield(upload_to="/images/imagethumb/")' change to upload_to="/media/"  ' ?

Comment: No. It will remain same. Your image will be saved in /media/images/imagethumb/ directory.

Comment: i create in the media the folder /images/imagethumb/ or create automatically from the django ?

Comment: It will be created automatically.

Comment: nice and the image where i want to upload my site must be  
inside the media/images/imagethumb/  ? or just  inside my pc ?

Comment: I do not understand your question. There are two types of image. 1: Logos. These are same for all users. These will be /static/ folder in your project. You can access it by /static/img.png. You do not have to create any model field for these images. Other type of image are those which are user spacific like profile picture. The thing which you ask in you above question is related to these images.

Comment: When you will save your form (I am supposing you are saving images through forms), django will create a filed in your db which will have path and name of your image and your image will be copied in /media/blah/blah/ folder. Hope you will understand.

Comment: For static file, you can read following documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

Comment: yeah my question is the images where i want to upload from 'image1 = model.imagefield(upload_to="/images/imagethumb/") must be specific  directory structure on my pc ?must be in the media folder ? or in the media/images/imagethumb ?

Comment: It will be uploaded from your pc through html file field. When you will submit your form, it will save on your server in /media/blah/... folder.

Comment: i thing so i have problem with the line on my mysite/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT),


show me error

Comment: You have to import settings. Write 'import settings' on top.

Comment: from django.conf.urls import include, url,static
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]
urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)    error again

Comment: what is error? Write details

Comment: i think its work now thnx very much you are so good you help me,now if i want upload static images for my static template i create a static folder in my project file and in my html template {% load staticfiles %} and <img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/> so easy now ?

Comment: can you help me with the static images for html template?

Comment: Check this article. It will help you.http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/templates_static.html
 It is not very difficult. Just create static folder as you created media folder. Save images in that folder. Add STATIC_URL is settings.py and path to static folder. your image path will be like /img/img.png (Suppose your image is in /static/img/img.png)

Comment: i find another solution thnx btw